# How do I provide a link to a changelog for a package on PyPI?

Tags: python, setuptools, pypi, python-packaging

Some PyPI projects provide a bunch of links in the sidebar, including to a changelog. For example, Django provides these links at https://pypi.org/project/Django/ :

[image: Screenshot]

How do I add a link to my project for a change log or a release log?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpypi%5D+%5Bsetuptools%5D+URLs

Comment: Where does the icon come from?

Comment: Among the answers at the duplicate question there is the link https://github.com/pypi/warehouse/blob/main/warehouse/templates/packaging/detail.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link to the change log is like other project links located in your `setup.py` or `setup.cfg` file.

If you are using `setuptools`, you can use the [`project_urls`](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/guides/distributing-packages-using-setuptools/#project-urls) keyword argument in your `setup.py` file, like this:

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name='foobar',
    version='1.0',
    # ...
    project_urls={
        'Documentation': 'https://example.com/documentation/',
        'GitHub': 'https://github.com/foobar/foobar/',
        'Changelog': 'https://github.com/foobar/foobar/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md',
    },
)
```

The `project_urls` keyword argument takes a dictionary mapping link captions to their URLs. The link captions can be anything you like, they will be displayed on the PyPI project page, so use English labels.

If you prefer to use `setup.cfg`, you can add these lines to your `setup.cfg`:

```
project_urls =
    Documentation = https://example.com/documentation/
    GitHub = https://github.com/foobar/foobar
    Changelog = https://github.com/foobar/foobar/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md
```

If you want to ensure that the icon used is the scroll icon, make sure the key used is one of these case-insensitive keys ([found here](https://github.com/pypi/warehouse/blob/main/warehouse/templates/packaging/detail.html)):

```
["changelog", "change log", "changes", "release notes", "news", "what's new", "history"]
```